# Is it possible not add a fields of id_user in my html structure. that id_user serve as my foreign key and it says I have an undefined array key error

Tags: php, array-key

Undefined Array Key about id_user expecting to automatically add the id in my attributes, id_user without adding any field of html structure and without an error and proceed to another operation of structuring php program

Comment: Probably yes. But you must explain all the details.

Comment: Look here: [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.